Impedance of a passive RC
I am simulating the input impedance of the following passive RC circuit.

Before the simulation, I calculated the impedance to be:
Zin = 5k + 5k + 1/(2pi20K*26pF) = 316.067 kOhms.
For the simulation, this is what I did:

Apply an AC=1 input signal to the circuit.
Perform ac simulation
Plot (VF(VIP1) - VF(VIN1)) / IF(VO/PLUS) = Zin.
See what the impedance value is at 20 kHz and compare the result with my calculation.

This was my simulation result:

My calculation and the simulation result are different.
Can you please show me where I have done wrong in calculating the impedance for the circuit?

Did you take into account the phase of current and voltage not being equal?

Have you learned complex numbers?

Thank you all very much :)  I managed to get the right answer.

The input impedance is \$\sqrt{R^2 + X_C^2}\$ and not \$R+X_C\$.
Pythagoras is king when it comes to adding resistive and reactive impedances.
The correct formula gives you the right answer of 306.2305175 kΩ.

Hi Andy, Thank you very much for your help. I understand it now. Z^2 = R^2 + XC^2. Hence, to find the input impedance, I need to do the following:  R=10k, XC = 1/(2pi20K*26pF) = 306.067k, Z=306.231k.
